# Regex : digits repeats 7 or 9 times

Tags: regex

It might so simple yet I'm struggling here...
I need a regex for a repeating number of digits which should match if the string is 7 or 9 digits in length

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking about repeating SAME digits 7 or 9 times or ANY digit 7 or 9 times ? Can you please clarify on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `(\d{7}|\d{9})`. This way you do not match an eight digits long string.

Edit I: As proposed by Alex (see comments) `\d{7}(\d{2})?` might even perform better.

Edit II: Okay, reread the question, got the problem. `\D\d{7}(\d{2})?\D` should do it. That also doesn't match 7 digits in a 8 digit number.

Edit III: Or use the word boundaries suggested by M42

Comment: \d{7}(\d{2})? might result in less backtracking

Comment: Actually `\d{7}(?:\d{2})?` would perform even better since it does not capture the second group.

Comment: Doesn't that only ever match the first 7 digits?

Comment: Well, anchors can help you with that, @LucasHoepner

Comment: Your second option actually won't work if the string is just `1234567` - word boundaries are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
\b\d{7}(?:\d\d)?\b
```

The word boundaries assure you have only 7 or 9 digit

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
This is for C#. But it should work for other languages.

```
(\d{7})|(\d{9})
```

This is how it works:

| means OR

{7} means match 7 times

\d represents any digit

Comment: @GuyZ You can try this one also: ((\d{7})\D+)|((\d{9})\D+)